# error con un GROUP BY en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

para poner en contexto mi pregunta adjuntare mi diseño de `BBDD`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero hacer una consulta que tenga

- id_persona
- nombre
- numero reuniones
- % asistencia
- % inasistencia
- % excusa
- jornada

este es el código que estado trabajando:

```
    SELECT
    pe.id_persona,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', pe.nombres, pe.apellidos) nombres,
    COUNT(pa.id_estado_participante) reuniones,
    ROUND(
        (
            SUM(pa.id_estado_participante = 1) / COUNT(pa.id_estado_participante)
        ) * 100
    ) asistencia,
    ROUND(
        (
            SUM(pa.id_estado_participante = 2) / COUNT(pa.id_estado_participante)
        ) * 100
    ) inasistencia,
    ROUND(
        (
            SUM(pa.id_estado_participante = 3) / COUNT(pa.id_estado_participante)
        ) * 100
    ) excusa
FROM
    tbl_personas pe
INNER JOIN tbl_participantes pa ON
    pa.id_persona = pe.id_persona
INNER JOIN tbl_horario_docentes hrd ON
    hrd.id_persona = pe.id_persona
INNER JOIN tbl_jornadas j ON
    j.id_jornada = hrd.id_jornada
INNER JOIN tbl_reunion t1 ON
    t1.id_reunion = pa.id_reunion
WHERE
    t1.fecha LIKE '%2021%'
GROUP BY
    pe.id_persona
ORDER BY
    nombres ASC
```

se mira asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema que para traer la ultima columna que quiero seria `jornada` que solo seria del poner `J.jORNADA` porque ya le puse el `inner join` pero me tira este error

lo pongo asi:

```
    SELECT
    pe.id_persona,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', pe.nombres, pe.apellidos) nombres,
    COUNT(pa.id_estado_participante) reuniones,
    ROUND(
        (
            SUM(pa.id_estado_participante = 1) / COUNT(pa.id_estado_participante)
        ) * 100
    ) asistencia,
    ROUND(
        (
            SUM(pa.id_estado_participante = 2) / COUNT(pa.id_estado_participante)
        ) * 100
    ) inasistencia,
    ROUND(
        (
            SUM(pa.id_estado_participante = 3) / COUNT(pa.id_estado_participante)
        ) * 100
    ) excusa,
    j.jornada  // este es la columna que estoy agragando
FROM
    tbl_personas pe
INNER JOIN tbl_participantes pa ON
    pa.id_persona = pe.id_persona
INNER JOIN tbl_horario_docentes hrd ON
    hrd.id_persona = pe.id_persona
INNER JOIN tbl_jornadas j ON
    j.id_jornada = hrd.id_jornada
INNER JOIN tbl_reunion t1 ON
    t1.id_reunion = pa.id_reunion
WHERE
    t1.fecha LIKE '%2021%'
GROUP BY
    pe.id_persona
ORDER BY
    nombres ASC
```

y me tira este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se cual es mi error en el group by porfavor si alguien me puede ayudar!!!!

Comment: Deberías agregar `j.jornada` al `GROUP BY` , si no es el caso que estes buscando agrupar por esta columna, debería entonces estar dentro de una función de agregación.

Comment: igualmente me sigue tirando error

Comment: El error que publicaste te esta diciendo que falta agregar la columna en el `group by` si la agregas como te dice, puede que te de un error, pero debería ser otro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu tabla Alias con `pe` no tiene problemas con el CONCAT ya que la incluyes en `GROUP BY`; sin embargo no estas incluyendo a `j` es por ello el error.

Dentro de las diversas opciones; pero en esta ocasión asumo que pa es la de detalle y las demás "son catálogos"; te sugiero que pa sea un subquery y así no modificas mucho; es decir que `INNER JOIN tbl_participantes pa ON`
sea:

```
INNER JOIN (
   select
      id_persona,
      COUNT(id_estado_participante) reuniones,
    ROUND(
        (
            SUM(id_estado_participante = 1) / COUNT(id_estado_participante)
        ) * 100
    ) asistencia,
    ROUND(
        (
            SUM(id_estado_participante = 2) / COUNT(id_estado_participante)
        ) * 100
    ) inasistencia,
    ROUND(
        (
            SUM(id_estado_participante = 3) / COUNT(id_estado_participante)
        ) * 100
    ) excusa
   FROM tbl_participantes 
   GROUP BY id_persona
) pa ON
```

todo lo demas igual pero eliminas el `GROUP BY pe.id_persona` que tienes después del `WHERE`.

Tu `SELECT` principal quedaría:

```
SELECT
   pe.id_persona,
   CONCAT_WS(' ', pe.nombres, pe.apellidos) nombres,
   pa.reuniones,
   pa.asistencia,
   pa.inasistencia,
   pa.excusa,
   j.jornada
FROM
[Todo lo demás con los cambios sugeridos]
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.